# Find cell that contains some phrase

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm looking for replacement of Excel formula:

```
=if.error(lookup(1000;search($B$1:$B$2;A1);$B$1:$B$2); "NONE")
```

The sheet looks like this:

[image]

So in column A, I have a long product index, in column B, I have a database of indexes. In column C, I want to receive an index from a database if a cell from column A contains it.

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LOOKUP(1000, SEARCH($B$1:$B$4, A1), 
                                          $B$1:$B$4), "NONE"))
```

[image: 9]

---

to make it more intuitive (this way you don't need to edit **B** range when your DB grows):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LOOKUP(1000, SEARCH(INDIRECT("$B$1:$B$"&COUNTA(B$1:B)), A1), 
                                          INDIRECT("$B$1:$B$"&COUNTA(B$1:B))), "NONE"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. The formula looks good but there's some glitch.
If you mind look at the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pq5mNsi31tOMn6fyvyuJ-H29s2Gvvr-mTj6RiClmvY4/edit?usp=sharing
If there's a two similar codes in database like 2240 and D2240 there's only one that can be find. I have multiple codes that short like 2240 and another one like 342240001. Any ideas how to fix it?